# Install pip<v8 in python3.2

Tags: pip, python-3.2

I fail to install pip in python3.2.
The newest version of pip (v8.x) seems to not support python3.2 any more.

So i tried: sudo python3 get-pip.py 'pip<8' but it still seems to install v8.x.

**Output:**

```
UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19178, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 195, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpec9tur/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpec9tur/pip.zip/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpec9tur/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpec9tur/pip.zip/pip/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpec9tur/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py", line 48
    empty_fill = u'∙'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

I used the wrong get-pip, as per documentation of get-pip

use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.2/get-pip.py

Comment: It says this when I run that get--pip.py:  `Collecting pip<8
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<8 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip<8` (python 3.2.2 64-bit)

Comment: I think with the ssl changes, installing pip in python 3.2 is not possible.  3.3 seems to be looked down on as well.

Comment: the link is broken bro, it looks like it changed to https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.2/get-pip.py

Answer (score 0):

As the bootstrap.pypa.io got updated so they changed the path of files or directories.

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.2/get-pip.py will not work

**This link will work** :
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.2/

Comment: As you have posted this in late 2021 - Any way you got the `Collecting pip<8   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<8 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pip<8` (mentioned also in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602120/install-pipv8-in-python3-2#comment111654724_37622659)) fixed?