# opencv for python installation

Tags: python, opencv

I have followed the instructions in here [http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/] , in order to install python3. I am using Ubtuno 12.04. Upon checking my python version, I have:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ python3 --version
Python 3.2.3
```

In Step 2, I use:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

but I receive the following error after running the second line:

```
/tmp/tmp4ijset/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
main()
File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
import pip
File "/tmp/tmp4ijset/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp4ijset/pip.zip/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp4ijset/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp4ijset/pip.zip/pip/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp4ijset/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py", line 48
empty_fill = u'∙'
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- Q1: What is the source of this error please and how can I solve it to have pip3 installed on my machine?
- Q2: How can I install openCV under python 3?

Comment: Maybe these links will help you: http://opencv.org/downloads.html (download OpenCV from here). https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3390 (Pip problem with Python 3.2)

Comment: Thanks. Can I update my python3 version to the latest? What is the best manner to do this in your view?

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get install python 3.5.2

Comment: I did it and still have the same python versions in my machine ?!

Comment: Maybe check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602120/install-pipv8-in-python3-2

Comment: Sorry I recieve the same error and my python version I am unable to upgrade to 3.5.2 ?1 :-(