# Python 3.2.2 [2018]: Cannot install Pip 7.1.2 (No matching distribution found for 7.1.2)

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm sure there have been others who had this same problem, but those kind of posts of been difficult to track down or don't help resolve my issue.

I'm trying to get an old Django project from 2015 up and running but it keep encountering runtime errors on the newer version of Django and Python. This project was originally built in Django 1.6.5 using Python 3.2.2, so I'm trying to recreate that dev environment so I can see the project working and hope to bring it up to standard with at least Python 3.4 and Django 1.11.

I have Python 3.2.2 installed, but I've run into problems getting Pip to install. I'm aware that Pip wasn't bundled with Python until 3.3, so I'm trying to install it myself using `get-pip` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.2/get-pip.py. When I execute this script it returns an error.

```
PS F:\temp> python get-pip.py 7.1.2
Collecting 7.1.2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 7.1.2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip 7.1.2
```

I found this post ([Install pip<v8 in python3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602120/install-pipv8-in-python3-2)) that led me to bootstrap.pypa.io, but the solutions there isn't helping.

Am I installing pip 7.1.2 correctly, or does it just flat out not exist anymore in 2018?

Comment: Django 1.6.x supported Python 3.3. There could be something else in your project that doesn’t support it, but I think you’d probably get away with creating the environment with 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

`setuptools` dropped support for Python 3.2 at version [30.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v30-0-0) so first thing is to downgrade setuptools:

```
pip install -U 'setuptools<30`
```

Then download [wheel for version 7.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/pip/7.1.2/#files) and install it:

```
pip install -U  pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

If that still doesn't work: download source code, untar the archive and run

```
python setup.py install
```